# Solving voltage dividers with unknown resistance

Tags: voltage-divider

This topic could have been in math as it is mainly about an algebra trick I don't know how to perform, but since it is about voltage dividers, I am sure a lot of people are qualified here.

I need to solve this equation, but I don't know how to isolate R.

24V * (R / (R + 1200ohm))  = 24V * (R / R + 6000ohm) + 5V

Here is a schematic to help, just in case. LVDT 1 has 20mA and LVDT 2 has 4mA. Vm is a differential of 5V.

[image]

Comment: These aren't voltage dividers.

Comment: To think of it another way, how large of a resistor will produce a voltage difference of 5V with a current change of 16mA?  E (Voltage) = I (Current) * R (Resistance).  There is an effort requirement for homework questions, so if that doesn't do it for you, you'll have to show us an attempt.

Comment: JCSB, It's very easy to write out the three equations and three unknowns for this. And I'm not sure where you come up with 1200 Ohm and 6000 Ohm in your equation. And I have a suspicion you didn't even get the equation down the way you wanted (wrong or otherwise) as you have an R / R on the right side, which is just 1 for most folks when R isn't zero, anyway. But I think you are supposed to just set up three equations and solve it. Can you spend some time and talk about what you see in the schematic and how you approached your equation? It would help us a lot.

Comment: Hint: The 24V is unimportant.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Agreed. It's not important.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany By the way, this problem immediately looked to me like: 1 simple equation, 2 more interesting equations, and 3 simultaneous not so interesting equations. All three perspectives at the same moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jonk and Spehro gave you some good hints, but maybe you need a schematic.

Sometimes there are tricks to help you solve a problem, sometimes not. If you don't see a quick way, do it the old fashioned way.

Realize that with a series current source, whatever is feeding that current doesn't matter.

Redraw in the simplest form possible, using standard symbols wherever possible.

Label the nodes.

Write equations.

Solve.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnyzzo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the circuit idea:

The two currents (20 mA and 4 mA) are converted to two voltage drops (20 mA x R) and (4 mA x R) that are subtracted from each other in a series manner (KVL). The resulting differential voltage (16 mA x R) represents (is proportional to) the current difference.

So this configuration is a *current subtractor with a voltage output*.